# python: How to change outlook get creation time format?

Tags: python, email, outlook

I want to change outlook creationTime format.

```
for message in sub.Items:
    subject = message.subject
    body = message.body
    sendTime = message.CreationTime
```

I get the message `creationTime` for using `message.CreationTime`.
When I print the `sendTime`, the result is 04/15/16 17:22:29. 
So I used `strftime` to change the date format but it does not work.

I imported such library in my source code.

```
import win32com.client
from datetime import datetime, date, time
import string
import pymysql
```

But an error occured:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\20_log\outlook\outlook.py", line 164, in <module> main()
File "D:\20_log\outlook\outlook.py", line 161, in main get_outlook_message()
File "D:\20_log\outlook\outlook.py", line 56, in get_outlook_message
sendTime.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
AttributeError: strftime
```

How can I change the outlook `creationTime` format?

Comment: Print `type(sendTime)` and see what sort of value `message.CreationTime` is which should help you determine what needs to be done to convert it (it doesn't appear to be a `datatime` object).

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I printed the type(sendTime) that result is <type 'time'>. And I also printed the value, that result is 04/15/16 17:22:29. I want to print the sendTime format like this 2016-04-15 17:22:29.

Comment: Strange...it should have a `strftime()` method. Try using the module level function `time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', sendTime)`

Comment: I printed the `time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', sendTime)` that retuns `TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.time' object but received a 'str'`

Comment: OK, that helps — see answer I've posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since (according to your comments) `sendTime` is a string, you can parse it into a [`time.struct_time`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.struct_time) using `time.strptime()`, which can then be formatted with `time.strftime()` like you're attempting to do.

```
import time

sendTime = '04/15/16 17:22:29'  # example value of message.CreationTime

# parse sendTime into a time.struct_time
sendTime_st = time.strptime(sendTime, '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S')

# format the returned struct_time into the desired format
print(time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', sendTime_st))
# another example
print(time.strftime('%a, %m-%b-%y at %H:%M:%S', sendTime_st))
```

Output:

```
17:22:29
Fri, 04-Apr-16 at 17:22:29
```

Comment: Thank you. I solved the problem. I replace the sendTime to string and then using datetime.strptime.

Answer (score 1):

`MailItem.CreationTime` is DateTime value, it does not have any format - it is not a string. On the low level (COM), it is an 8 byte float with the integer number being the number of days since `1/1/1900` and the fractional part being the time of the day.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Is there any way to print the value like this 2016-04-15 17:22:29 ??

Comment: Nonsense, of course it has a format, otherwise it would not be useful for any purpose, much less representing a date. After _much_ digging through the MS documentation it appears that the lowest level, the 8 byte value is "a 64-bit integer representing the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601".

Comment: @Bethlee - you would need to format the datetime appropriately. How you do that in Python, I do not know.

Comment: @Martineau  You are mixing format (as in textual representation, which is what the OP wants) and the internal data representation. And what you are describing is the FILETIME structure used in Windows API. FILETIME is not used in IDispatch-friendly COM.  COM uses 8 byte float.

Comment: Yes, I'm describing the Windows `FILETIME` structure, which what the MSDN documentation (ultimately) says is the type of the `CreationTime` property. For the record, the (_Computers_) [definition](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/format) of "format" could apply to either the internal data and string representation (or both).

Comment: Where does MSDN say that? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867230.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: While I _could_ provide a series of links showing the (long and winding) path I followed through the documentation, it's irrelevant to the question at this point, so I not going to bother...

Comment: Once again, MailItem.CreationTime property returns an 8 byte float. Just like all other objects  that return DateTime values in the Outlook Object Model - it is standard in the IDispatch-friendly COM world. You are mistaking MailItem.CreationTime property for the PR_CREATION_TIME Extended MAPI property (not accessible in Python or any scriptable language) - PR_CREATION_TIME and other PT_SYSTIME MAPI properties indeed use the FILETIME structure (SPropValue.Value.ft).

Comment: Thank you so much to Dmitry Streblechenko and  martineau. I can learn more about the outlook.